# Query For Dynamic Reports

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a requirement for the following logic to be implemented. lets Assume there is a property listbox where user gives the input.

1. When the field left blank. It should show message "All properties Selected" in d report
2. If the user selects or gives   multiple properties.It should display the properties selected like xxx,yyy,zzz selected
3. SO now if user selects all the properties manually from d drop down list,i wanna display All properties selected .

Implemented now for 1st two requirements. Can any1 give some idea regarding the 3rd Demand

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could do the following:

1. Create a parameter.
2. Set the parameter to internal.
3. Make it a multi-select parameter.
4. Set the available values to a data set that returns the list of all possible fields.
5. Set the default value to the data set that returns the list of all possible fields.  Basically, you are selecting all by default in the internal parameter.
6. In the data set that executes your report code, add code that compares the count of records from the internal parameter to the count of records from the parameter that users can see for selecting records.  If the counts are equal, then the user has selected all possible properties.

If I misunderstood and you are trying to get the parameter box itself to vary it's output, then this won't help.

Comment: I cant really Hardcode dat way. the Number of inputs may vary n d near future. Anyway Thanks :)

Comment: There's nothing to hard code.  I use a similar approach on a report that originally had about 40 selectable output fields and now it has over 120.  There is a control table that I add possible field values to and it flows through to the report.

Answer (score 0):

This expression will check the number of selected values against the number of available values and display "All properties selected" when all the properties are selected and will list the selected properties when only some of the values are selected:

```
=iif(Parameters!YourParameterName.Count=CountRows("YourParameterSelectDataset"),
    "All properties selected",join(Parameters!YourParameterName.Value,","))
```